# Find element that has either class 1 or class 2

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to find text inside an element whose class is either myClass1 OR myClass2.

```
var myText = $(this).find('.myClass1:first').text();
```

This works fine but I am unsure if/how I can check for one of 2 classes (my element will only have one class out of these 2 I mentioned).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: do you want only one result (*the first found*)? or the first of each (*two results*) ?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

If you want the first one found (*but only one*) use

```
var myText = $(this).find('.myClass1,.myClass2').eq(0).text();
```

If you want the first of each kind (*two results*) then look at the answer provided by [@jelbourn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196385/find-element-that-has-either-class-1-or-class-2/4196410#4196410).

Comment: this was exactly what I was after, but will take note of the other suggestions as well for future need :) thanks everyone

Answer (score 29):

You can separate your selectors with commas to generate a list containing all elements with either class (or with both):

```
var elements = $(this).find('.myclass1:first, .myclass2:first');
```

Answer (score 15):

Enter a comma between the two classes in your selector.

```
$(".a, .b")
```

this will match all elements with class "a" OR class "b"

http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Answer (score 4):

Use an if statement and the jQuery hasClass() function:

http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

It would probably look something like this:

```
if($(this).hasClass('myClass1') || $(this).hasClass('myClass2')) {
  myText = $(this).text();
} else {
  myText = null;
}
```