# Can we put OR condition in .find() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do something like :

```
$(".test").find("button or input[type=button]")
```

How can i do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find element that has either class 1 or class 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196385/find-element-that-has-either-class-1-or-class-2) and maybe [How do I combine logical OR with logical AND within a jQuery attribute selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404995/how-do-i-combine-logical-or-with-logical-and-within-a-jquery-attribute-selector).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's called the [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector) and it's a comma:

```
$(".test").find("button, input[type=button]")
```

For the sake of completeness, note that [`:button`](http://api.jquery.com/button-selector/) does exactly this, but will be slower in pretty much all modern browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Just use comma ie `$(".test").find("button, input[type=button]");`

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".test").find("button, input[type=button]")
```